# ProtocolError in Chroma Client Mode

Tags: docker, vector-database, chromadb

I deploy the Chroma server in container, while i using function "collection.add()", it shows ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, ''An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)).

- What i add is a 45MB PDF(it has been splited)
- I create the container with command "docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --shm-size=2g --name chromadb_server --mount source=chroma-main_index_data,target=/opt/chromadb server:92ac0c33c51f"
- "server:92ac0c33c51f" is a local image.
- Functions like "collection.list_collection()" work fine

I suspect it's a storage space issue, i still can add smaller text data, but once i add too much the problem arises.

Besides Chroma, is there others open-source vector databse?